# Notation in infinite sums and infinite unions, some questions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, notation

Yesterday I see this expression:

$$(a, b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a + 1/n, b - 1/n]$$

The first thing that I thought was "why this expression represent an **open** interval and not a closed one?" Then I suppose that this is because the above expression doesn't represent a limit, if it would be a limit then it would represent a closed interval instead of an open one.

I dont know if my reasoning is ok or not, and this is one of the reasons to ask in mathexchange.

A) Then my first question is: it is ok my reasoning or it is not correct? And if it is not correct please, can someone explain to me why the infinite union doesn't represent a closed interval? Because is clear that $1/n$ when $n=\infty$ is zero.

B) Now the second question is, there is an abuse of notation when someone write $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k)=c$ where $c\in\Bbb R$? I assume, because I read in some books, that a infinite summation represent a limit of a partial sum, so it makes sense that converges to a real number (or complex).

C) And the final question is, maybe

$$(a, b)= \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} [a + 1/n, b - 1/n]$$

is a better expression than the original?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's... a union, not a *limit*. There's really no "limit" involved in the definition of union. However, it *is* true that the endpoints of the closed intervals, taken as sequences, has limits $a,b$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, I know @BrianO, but the question is if the notation is not good, if you compare it with a summation where limit is not explicit but it is a limit.

Comment: Right, but a union is not a sum. Your question C) is relevant: it may be a better notation for *you* to use now :) The notations are equivalent, but the one in C) doesn't have any similarity to the usual sum notation.

Comment: Re A): If the union is a closed interval $[a,b]$, then e.g. $a$ is a member of the union. So it must belong to one of the closed intervals being joined (union'ed). Which one could that be, exactly?

Comment: PS for unions and intersections of indexed families, it's customary to use \bigcup and \bigcap, rather than \cup and \cap.

Comment: Yes, right... the definition of set make no sense... but we must consider $n$ just a natural number. If $n$ would be an hyperreal number then maybe you can take the closed interval. It is fine or not @BrianO? (Yes, I just copied the expression somewhere, it is better big cap and so).

Comment: No need for hyperreals here. The union is over that countable family of closed intervals, indexed by the real true integers. "the definition of set makes no sense" -- which def, what set?

Comment: @BrianO, all ok... just cant write a lot here. I tried to say that you are right... if it would be closed then a and b must be in some set, by the definition of set. I tried to say that taking the closed interval doesnt make sense with the definition of set.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then there you go: that's why the endpoints are not included.

Comment: By the way, the "equality" $(a,b)=\bigcup_1^\infty \dots$ is not necessarily correct. For example let $a=3.14$ and $b=3.1416$.  But it is correct in this case if we start the union at say $n=2000$.

Comment: I am not fond of formulas when words work better, countable union of closed sets. But $\bigcup_1^\infty F_n$, where the $F_n$ are closed sets, will do.  So will $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} F_n$. Both are in common use.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Good point.  This statement implicitly assumes $a + 2 \le b$ or (more likely) either the index starts and the first n where $1/n \le (b -a)/2$ or that it is assumed $I_n = [\min(a + 1/n, a + (b-a)/2), \max(b - 1/n, b - (b-a)/2)]$.  Perhaps a better way of expressing this was $I_n = [a + (b-a)/2n, b - (b-a)/2n]$.  But it doesn't change the concept or result at all and just bogs us down in tedious book keeping.  Perhaps it's just easier to assume, wolog, $(b -a) \ge 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

""why this expression represent an open interval and not a closed one?""

Because that particular union of closed intervals *is* an open interval.  Nothing to do with representations or limits or anything.  The union simply *is* an open interval*.

It's easy to show that i) for $x \le a$ or $x \ge b$ then $x \notin$ any $[a + 1/n, b -1 /n] $ and ii) for $a < x < b$ then $x \in [a + 1/n, b - 1/n]$ for some $n \in N$.  So the union does in every sense of the word equal (a, b).

B) Infinite sums are limits of sequences of finite partial sums.  That would be an abuse of notation except the notation was specifically defined to mean a limit so you can't abuse a definition.

But a sum is an entirely different thing than a union.  You *can* have infinite unions and I don't think you can have limits of unions.  You *can't* have infinite sums and you can have limits of sums.

C)  Your notation and the original notation both mean exactly the same thing and both are used and can be used interchangeably.

* It is worth noting all *finite* unions of closed sets are closed.  But not necessarily all *infinite* unions are closed as this example clearly demonstrates.  However all intersections, finite or infinite are closed.

All unions of open sets, finite or infinite, are open.  All finite intersections of open sets are open, but not all infinite intersections of open sets are open.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much... the order relations point the thing definitively clear. What confused to me is that it resembles a lot a convergent sequence.

Comment: Well, there are similarities.  The end points form sequences that converge but the limits of these sequences are extrema and *not* max or mins of the sequence.  The limits *don't* exist in the sequence.  You can have a sequence of infinite unions but to define this as *converging* sequence you need to define some metric to measure unions in real values.  This maybe can be done but that's not the point of unions which are very concrete things.